# How can I make a copy of a branch created on the release branch

Tags: git

I want to make a copy of a feature branch (on my local where the feature branch is created from master branch )---> from a branch on release .

Master---> release ---> feature

want to make a copy of the feature to local so I can merge it to master.I know its a bit confusing but please help

Comment: What do you mean when you say "copy"? Do you mean only the commits on the feature branch, but not release itself? Are you trying to backport a hot patch?

Answer (score 1):

***UPDATE***

I think you've made a hot patch to the release branch and now need to move it back to production.

Your situation is this.

```
A - B [master]
     \
      C - D [release]
           \
            E - F [feature]
```

You want this:

```
      E1 - F1 [feature_copy]
     /
A - B [master]
     \
      C - D [release]
           \
            E - F [feature]
```

First, make a new branch at feature.

```
$ git branch feature_copy feature

A - B [master]
     \
      C - D [release]
           \
            E - F [feature]
                  [feature_copy]
```

Then rebase just the parts after release onto master.

```
# "rebase the commits from just after release to feature_copy onto master"
$ git rebase --onto master release feature_copy

      E1 - F1 [feature_copy]
     /
A - B [master]
     \
      C - D [release]
           \
            E - F [feature]
```

And example of this is in [the git-rebase documentation](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-rebase#_description).

---

***Previous answer***

Git branches are just labels pointing to commits. Making a "copy" means making a new branch label pointing at the same commit as feature.

```
git branch feature_copy feature
```

> want to make a copy of the feature to local so I can merge it to master.

But you don't need a copy. Simply merge feature into master.

```
git checkout master
git merge feature
```

Only master is altered, feature is not changed.

```
A - B - C [master]
         \
          D - E - F [feature]

$ git checkout master
$ git merge feature

A - B - C --------- M [master]
         \         /
          D - E - F [feature]
```

(That would actually be a "fast-forward", but let's not confuse things)